# Categorize Data within table and count based upon results

Tags: sql, count

Is it possible to categorize data withing a table and to count the number of times it occurs?

For instance, I am trying to pull a query that categorizes lives data by: 1-9 Lives, 10-49 Lives, 50-199 Lives..etc, and then count the number of clients that fit those criteria?

So I want it to show as below.

```
Lives Category | Number of Clients
1-9 Lives  | 10
10-49 Lives  | 20
50-199 Lives  | 4
```

So far I have created this query

```
        SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN t1.clean_ft_ee_cnt > 0 and t1.clean_ft_ee_cnt < 10 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "1-9 Lives",
        COUNT(CASE when t1.clean_ft_ee_cnt > 9 and t1.clean_ft_ee_cnt < 50 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "10-49 Lives",
        COUNT(CASE when t1.clean_ft_ee_cnt > 49 and t1.clean_ft_ee_cnt < 200 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "50-199 Lives",
        COUNT(CASE when t1.clean_ft_ee_cnt > 199 and t1.clean_ft_ee_cnt < 500 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "200-499 Lives",
        COUNT(CASE when t1.clean_ft_ee_cnt > 499 and t1.clean_ft_ee_cnt < 2000 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "500-1,999 Lives",
        COUNT(CASE when t1.clean_ft_ee_cnt > 1999 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "2,000+ Lives",
        COUNT(CASE when t1.clean_ft_ee_cnt = 0 or t1.clean_ft_ee_cnt is NULL then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "Unknown Lives",
        count(t1.clean_ft_ee_cnt) as "Total Clients"
        FROM [GrpReposUserDev1_dv].[mvpGA].[mvp_client_data_t] t1
```

which does work, however it displays horizontally in different columns.

Comment: Use a case expression in a sub-query to put each value in a "lives group". GROUP BY its result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the bound conditions you have provided here seems pretty much static, we can create a derived table that uses the T-SQL `table value constructor` to specify multiple rows for the base table as:

```
select 
       BT.Lives_Category ,
       count(CT.clean_ft_ee_cnt) as Number_of_Clients
from @mvp_client_data_t CT
join
             --base table here
 (
             select * from 
             (values ('1-9',1,9),
                     ('10-49',10,49),
                     ('50-199',50,199)
             )
             as Base_Table (Lives_Category,MinCnt,MaxCnt)
 ) BT    
 on CT.clean_ft_ee_cnt between BT.MinCnt and BT.MaxCnt
 group by BT.Lives_Category
```

[Sample code here..](https://rextester.com/ZZTN2617)